# using iterator to get phrases in a string.

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have vectors that contain many sentences such as "hello there how are you". I want to be able to extract phrases of size 2 and 5 from a sentence, which then I will store in another vector. For example, from the string above, I hope to get "hello there" "hello there how" 
"hello there how are" and "hello there how are you".

I attempted by splitting the sentence into separate words and stored them in a vector using :

```
while( getline(stream, word, ' ') )
{

    vecWord.push_back(word);
}
```

This removed all the white spaces and stored each word. I understand that an iterator points to each element in a vector. How do I use an iterator to point to each element (aka each word) and combine them into size 2 - 5

any help would be appreciated

Comment: So, for "a b c d e f g", given the substring "c d e", you would print "c d e", "c d e f", and "c d e f g"?

Comment: yes. I want to be able to get "phrases" of the string. thats why i thought about using an iterator. is it possible?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes. The ambiguity comes the use of "phrases".

Comment: i will have to edit this post. it is a bit vague

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Given `all`, which is the list of all words, and `target`, which is the list of words in the desired substring. This can be decomposed into too separate problems. First, find the substring, then find all the following subtrings that include it. The first part is really similar to the general question of how to find a substring in a string. That is, how to find "45x" in "abc7845xyz". If grasping how iterators are used is the idea of what you're doing, I'd suggest looking up string searching algorithms writing using normal C array index style iteration and try converting them to iterators.

```
for(auto i = all.begin();i < all.end() - target.size();i++){
    auto temp_i = i;
    bool found = found = true;
    for(auto j = target.begin();found && j < target.end();j++, temp_i++)
        found = *temp_i == *j;

    // Substring found, so print all subsequent substrings containing it.
    if(found){
        auto start = i;
        for(auto end = i + target.size();end < all.end();end++){
           for(auto j = start;j <= end;j++)
               cout << j << " ";
           cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```